# PHP & Angular 2 - "live" direct messaging w/ own API and database

Tags: php, mysql, angular, private, messaging

I've researched "a lot" about live-chat applications and whatnot, but I couldn't really find the missing piece or the direction that I should go in.

**What I'm looking for.**
A private, direct messaging system between two users without sending fetch-requests on fixed intervals.

**What we already have.**
A full PHP Rest API w/ MySQL for our entire application including users, posts, messages, profiles, .. and an entire Angular 5 client-side application.

The current messaging system runs on basic POST's to send messages and GET's to fetch new messages (every 30 seconds) (It was never the intention for a real-time chat application back then)

Database and API-wise, there are 'conversations' between two UserID's and each conversation holds the messages with a UserID-from.

**Found suggestions:**

- Sockets (via Socket.io or something like that): The "issue" is that we're at least aiming at like 10k+ users by the end of the summer. Sockets would probably wreck our server or at least our PHP API if there are like 500+ open sockets or am I mistaken? (our current situation with the GET's probably as well..)
- Firebase: But this has it's own separate database and whatnot and not sure how to combine that with our existing API and authentication and such.
- 100+ topics and situation that are just about a "chatroom"-like application and not about direct messaging between two registered users.

I also had the idea to create a separate micro-service for the messaging part, based on an NodeJS Express server, but then again, the clients would need an open socket to that server and not just 'a socket', but a private channel for just those two users? (And then I'd would have to use some dirty nodejs-mysql parts for the UserID's and the authentication instead of running everything in Mongo for example)

At this point.. I'm not sure which direction to go in and how to implement that without having to "give" our messaging data to a third party server like Firebase for example or to waste valuable time by trying 4-5 different methods.

I know I'll probably have to rewrite our entire client-side application messaging part, but that is the least of my concerns.

What direction should I go in and with what kind of thoughts? Maybe someone with the same kind of situation that needed to convert an existing datababse-conversation-users-stuffs application?

Comment: Socket would more than likely be it. That is probably by far the best use case for them. Why do you think this would wreck you app?

Comment: I can't really find performance benchmarks or something like that when there are for example 200+ open connections to the server. It "scares" me, just the idea about a connection that is constantly active and open between the client and the server and that for 200+ connections while running an active API that handles about 1000+ requests :D I've always developed with the "close/end when done" principle to prevent remaining open connections to servers or databases.

Comment: Best way to benchmark is try it. Fortunately mocking up a load with them would not be hard with some bots. If we were all scared of the unknown where would we be?

Comment: You've got a point, good sir. My current train of thought would be to let all the requests still run via the PHP API, but let the sockets be handled via NodeJS, so that PHP broadcasts to the Node server and updates the listeners (this will at least get rid of the timed GET intervals). But I'll first try just using PHP sockets and see/test what the performance is to prevent complexity and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update. I've implemented to whole Socket-part and it's running perfectly!

Currently I have a NodeJS (WebSocket) Socket server running where the clients connect to on startup.

The PHP API sends a cURL POST request to that socket server with the clientId and the payload (different types, different bodies, ..). The socket-server checks if that client is connected (via an ID-connection lookup array) and forwards that message to that client. Then the client handles the incoming message type to check which action to execute with the payload.

No issues or remarks on the performance-side. Just some issues with IE users that have issues connecting with the socket server.

Currently in use for real-time notifications, chat messages, post-feeds updates, ..